# Route53 configuration for multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-route53

I have in my AWS 3 Accounts:

- root account
- prod account
- dev account

The root account is our master account we use for billing.

I have registered a domain (rootaccount.com) in Route53 with my root account. Name it here rootacount.com
I created a hosted zone for rootaccount.com. I got one NS and one SOA record.

Inside the prod account I have added a hosted zone for the subdomain prod.rootaccount.com
I got also a NS and SOA entry.

Back to the root account I added a NS record for prod.rootaccount.com and copied the NS values from prod.rootaccount.com to it. (I copied with te dot at the end)
So in the root account I have now inside the rootaccount.com hosted zone

```
rootaccount.com NS  Simple  -   No  
ns-8xxx.net.
ns-1xxx.co.uk.
ns-2xxx.com.
ns-1xxx.org.

rootaccount.com SOA Simple  -   No  ns-xxx.net. awsdnsxxx

prod.rootaccount.com    NS  Simple  -   No  
ns-3xxx.com.
ns-5xxx.net.
ns-1xxx.org.
ns-1xxx.co.uk.
```

Inside the prod.rootaccount.com i have:

```
prod.rootaccount.com    NS  Simple  -   No  
ns-3xxx.com.
ns-5xxx.net.
ns-1xxx.org.
ns-1xxx.co.uk.

prod.rootaccount.com    SOA Simple  -   No  ns-3xxx.com. awsdnsxxx

test.prod.rootaccount.com   A   Simple  -   Yes dualstack.k8s-ctrlroutexxx (ALB)
```

But it is not possible to get a connection to test.prod.rootaccount.com. Anything I have missed here? Error I got inside the browser is DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 0):

I've never registered domain in Route53, but I don't think it's different from GoDaddy or NameCheap.

You *shouldn't* create Hosted Zones in two accounts. Create it in the account where you are going to use (especially with integrated services like CloudFront or ELB). Most likely, in your prod account. *Don't* create it in root account.

Modify registrar record with NS values that you got in Hosted Zone. Don't change NS records in Hosted zone!

Now Route 53 registrar (or whoever AWS is using) points to your Hosted Zone. Create A / CNAME / whatever records in your one and only hosted zone, and you are good to go!